# How to determine if a surface exists

Tags: differential-geometry

Given that the coefficients of the first fundamental form are $E=G=1\ F=0$ and the coefficients of the second fundamental form are $L=1\ M=0\ N=-1$. How does one determine if the surface exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a surface $S$ is isometric to the plane, so using theorema egregium, Gauss curvature $K$ of $S$ is just $0$. However, you also have $K= \frac{LN-M^2}{EG-F}=-1$. Therefore, $S$ cannot exist.

Comment: "...Gauss curvature $K$ of $S$ is just $1$."  Do you mean $0$?

Comment: @JesseMadnick: Of course! I edited, thank you.